# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used in popup menu item

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, error-handling

when am getting an error in list parameter that **This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.**  i don't know what i have to do to fix this error . please help.

```
PopupMenuItem(
                                             onTap: () {
                                               var list = inventoryController
                                              .myInventoryList1
                                              .removeWhere((i) =>
                                               i.description ==inventoryController.myInventoryList1[index].description);
                                               inventoryController.deleteInventory(list, context);

                                             },
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is return type is `void`

```
   var list = inventoryController.myInventoryList1.removeWhere((i) =>
i.description ==inventoryController.myInventoryList1[index].description);
```

The next method u are calling needs to use `list` which is void because the method `removeWhere` returns a void and is assigned to `var list`